# Splunk Phantom API Retrieve Document from Vault

Tags: splunk

Using the Splunk Phantom API I can retrieve information about a document in a container like this:
`https://[myphantom_url]/rest/vault_document/24545`

Next, I want to download the document. Is that possible with the API? And if so, what is the endpoint I use? I looked through the [Phantom API documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Phantom/4.10.7/PlatformAPI/Using) and could not find an endpoint that would download a document.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Phantom/4.10.7/PlatformAPI/RESTVault, it *appears* you're doing the right thing already:

[image: API example]

[image: sample document returned]

What seems *not* to be happening when you hit that API endpoint?